# Angular : Multiselect dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using this [library](http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/) to create multiselect dropdown. everything's fine .
but there is something i can't handle it .
in source file there is `displayProp: 'label'` ,it means in json you should have a field call `label`, like this :

```
[{ id: 1, label: "David" }, { id: 2, label: "Jhon" }, { id: 3, aaa: "Danny" }];
```

**here's my problem :**
if i have database without label field, i have to change  `displayProp: 'label'` , but what if i have 2 multi select dropdown in my form from 2 jason with differnt field ?
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/), you can have multiple selects using different labels quite easily. Just use `extra-settings` attribute when creating a particular select and specify `displayProp` just for that one select.

Answer (score 0):

I have personally had problems with this library and finally used [angular-multi-select](http://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/) instead but I also ran into the problem with the label for the multi-select.

I would suggest looking at this library but you will still need a custom controller, service or factory (depending on what you are doing and the code conventions in place) to mutate whatever you have in your database into the label you need for your multi-select and also something in place to handle the ticked properties of every object in the list which would essentially be a for loop and an if-statement.

Comment: With every multi-select library for angular that I have tried, I have found that chrome debug tools like AngularJS Batarang mess with the dom and tend to break these libraries, they are quite temperamental.